# Docker swarm mode couldn't connect to another container

Tags: mysql, docker, swarm

I created a docker swarm mode cluster and an app deployed. When the app tries to connect to the database, it fails. I able make it work with "docker run" but not in docker swarm mode.

**Docker versions**

> Client:
> Version:      1.13.0
> API version:  1.25
> Go version:   go1.7.3
> Git commit:   49bf474
> Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:58:26 2017
> OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
>
> Server:
> Version:      1.13.0
> API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
> Go version:   go1.7.3
> Git commit:   49bf474
> Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:58:26 2017
> OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
> Experimental: false

**Error:**

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

**Docker commands used**

```
sudo docker network create -d overlay cross
sudo docker service create --name database  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin --replicas 3 -p 3306:3306 --network cross mysql --max_allowed_packet=500M

sudo docker service create --name cross_app --replicas 2 -p 8000:8080 --network cross app1
```

**Ports are open:**

> sudo docker exec -it 547ed77047c7 nc -v -z database 3306
> database (10.0.0.2:3306) open

Comment: It would help to know how you are contacting the database--what is the url? If you did a `curl` from the "cross_app" container (assuming curl actually does something against mysql), then it would look like `http://database:3306/`.